# ERELEASEBRANCHES The release branches are invalid in the `branches` configuration. when I use object

Tags: git, semantic-release

I'm using semantic-release, and I'm trying to create prerelease with configuration

```
module.exports = {
    branches: [{ name: 'master', prerelease: true }],
    plugins: [
        '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer',
        '@semantic-release/release-notes-generator',
        [
            '@semantic-release/github',
            {
                assets: [ { path: 'dist.zip', label: 'PWA App' } ],
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

As you can see the `branches` its's just an object with name and prerelase (I also tried to use as array, same problem)

Public repository with the error:
https://github.com/Ridermansb/react-firebase-ssr/runs/813996442?check_suite_focus=true

**THE ERROR**

> semantic-release "--dry-run" "--debug"

> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 17.1.1
> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/github"
> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/github"
> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/github"
> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "success" from "@semantic-release/github"
> [6:31:02 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "fail" from "@semantic-release/github"
> [6:31:10 PM] [semantic-release] › ⚠  Skip step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github" in dry-run mode

> A minimum of 1 and a maximum of 3 release branches are required in the branches configuration (https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#branches).

> This may occur if your repository does not have a release branch, such as master.

> Your configuration for the problematic branches is [].

> { AggregateError:
> SemanticReleaseError: The release branches are invalid in the `branches` configuration.
> at module.exports (/Users/ridermansb/Projects/meve.ai/web/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-error.js:6:10)
> at Object.entries.reduce (/Users/ridermansb/Projects/meve.ai/web/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:44:19)
> at Array.reduce ()
> at module.exports (/Users/ridermansb/Projects/meve.ai/web/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:34:46)
> at module.exports (/Users/ridermansb/Projects/meve.ai/web/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:66:11)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'AggregateError' }npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

---

I Also create tickets on [semantic-release/github](https://github.com/semantic-release/github/issues/276) and [semantic-release/semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/1587) repo

Answer (score 14):

I solved my issue by adding  `"release": { "branches": [ "master" ] },`
in package.json and remove it from the module.exports
https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/v/beta/usage/configuration

Answer (score 7):

You need to have at least one `release` branch specified. This branch needs to exist in the remote repository.

Comment: This was my problem, just to elaborate a little it was because the release branch I specified did not exist on remote. Once I pushed/created it semantic-release worked.